# Parallel workers with guarantee of processing

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, architecture

I have some tasks stored in a table of SQL-Server. Every task can be long-running. I want to process them on parallel workers. For example run more workers when load is high, and stop them, when no need. And when one worker is unavailable or failed his job, the processing task should return in queue.

What is the best way to organize queue and multiply workers with guarantee of processing? Tasks storage can be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use MS SQL table as a queue, store all requests in this queue, run multiply workers with Quartz.NET. Every worker receive one request. Every request is processing only by one worker.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Transacted MSMQ Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751493(v=vs.110).aspx). This allows you to push, store and process messages in a transactionnal way. There are basicly three main steps to implement to get what you need:

1. Create a persistent queue so that the messages are not lost if there's a power outage, etc.
2. Create a publisher service to push messages to the queue.
3. Create a consumer service to read and process messages from the queue.

If you follow the guideleine from the article a message will be returned to the queue in case the consumer service fails to process it. The solution is highly scalable. You can add as many consumer services as you wish in an adhoc way, just start up a new consumer service on a different machine and it will start reading and processing the messages from the queue. You can also control how many threads a consumer can use by changing maxConcurrentCalls behaviour setting:

```
<behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior  name="Throttled">
         <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="1" />
      </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

> The default is 16 times the processor count.

Please note, increasing the number of threads might not be very efficient especially if your tasks are CPU intensive.

Hope it helps!